# How can I define a global random number generator?

Tags: global-variables, rust, static-variables

I've tried both

```
static mut rng:XorShiftRng = XorShiftRng::new_unseeded();
static mut rng:Rng + 'static = rand::weak_rng();
```

But neither work. Is it a way to do so?

**Edit**

I want to make a module that has some recursive functions needing random numbers. I don't want the user to supply a random number generator neither do I want to supply a struct to user. So I hope there is a module-wise RNG.

Comment: The short answer is you can't. Can you add a bit more about why you want to do this? That would help us understand what you want to do and what kind of answer would be best.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Rust 1.0**

In Rust 1.0, `task_rng` was moved to the `rand` crate and is now known as [`thread_rng`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/rand/rand/fn.thread_rng.html).

**Original**

If you simply want the ability to have a for-free random number generator, I'd suggest looking at [TaskRng](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/rand/fn.task_rng.html):

> Retrieve the lazily-initialized task-local random number generator, seeded by the system.

You can always just grab one of these as an easy-to-use RNG.

As an aside: I've always found it useful to be able to provide my own RNG to code. It's fine to have a default value when the consumer doesn't need that power, but the ability to reproduce a particular string of random numbers is very useful for performance or functionality testing, for example.

Comment: So you're saying that task_rng() function call always returns the same system RNG without performance penalty. Is that right?

Comment: [Check the source](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/blob/4a4c89c7a4a763c253a97ff04647f52aca6a5490/src/libstd/rand/mod.rs#L329-L354) for full information, but each task (thread) has its own RNG, so there's a tiny performance hit *once per task*.